# How to change output depending upon command exit status in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I am working on a bash shell, While writing a script I thought to change the output and error massage of a command.

For Example the command is

```
sudo apt install nano
```

I want to give output

```
Installing nano
```

When command finishes successfully then

```
Nano Installed
```

Otherwise

```
Error occurred
```

While doing so I tried this

```
printf "\n Installing Nano"
{
  sudo apt install nano -y
} &> /dev/null
printf "\r Nano Installed \n"
```

but it not show distinct values for different exit status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing up two different things, success vs. failure and stdout vs stderr. The stdout vs. stderr distinction really has to do with a command's "normal" output (stdout) vs. status messages (stderr, including error messages, success messages, status messages, etc). In your case, *all* of the things you're printing should go to stderr, not stdout.

Success vs failure is a different question, and it's generally detected by the exit status of the command. It's a bit strange-looking, but the standard way to check the exit status of a command is to use it as the condition of an `if` statement, something like this:

```
printf "\n Installing Nano" >&2
if sudo apt install nano -y &> /dev/null; then
    # The "then" branch runs if the condition succeeds
    printf "\r Nano Installed \n" >&2
else
    # The "else" branch runs if the condition fails
    printf "\r Error Occured  \n" >&2
fi
```

(Using `&&` and `||` instead of `if ... then ... else` can cause confusion and weird problems in some situations; I do not recommend it.)

Note: the `>&2` redirects output to stderr, so the above sends *all* messages to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

While Trying to do so i found out a way

```
printf "\n Installing Nano"
sudo apt install nano &> /dev/null &&
printf "\r Nano Installed\n" ||
printf "\r Error Occured\n"
```

I think this will work for all

Comment: `printf "\r Error Occured\n" 1>&2` will redirect error messages to the std-err stream. Good luck.